# Magento 2 cron_schedule table increasing and CPU 100%

Tags: magento2, cron, sql

I updated to 2.2.1 from 2.1.10 and that looked good. But my CPU is increasing a lot and it went to over 100% in a few days.

The problem is the cron jobs because also the table cron_schedule was very full with 249.000 rows.

Any idea what causes the problem in the cronjobs?

Comment: I've seen bigger cron_schedule table, but you have a point, it should be dealt with.  
Can use this query to get the most frequent crons :
`SELECT count(*), job_code FROM cron_schedule group by job_code order by count(*) DESC`

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @manoM I did, but now 2 years ago. So i don't know the exact sollution anymore

Answer (score 6):

Maybe our [questions are related](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203131/bin-magento-cronrun-running-for-a-long-time)

edit/update: clearing your `cron_schedule` table should temporarily fix your problem:

```
TRUNCATE cron_schedule;
```

to permanently fix your problem you have to find out why your cron_schedule table is growing. In my case, it is the missing mail server!

if you don't care about indexing and sending emails, you could also disable your crontab entries.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, turns out the slow query was an update join on the cron_schedule table.

Found a related site on this.
Solution - You can clear it with a daily script to delete completed records.
https://www.optiweb.com/magento-2-cron-issues/

There should be a configuration for each cron groupfor the history cleanup and lifetimes.

```
<history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
<history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime> 
<history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
```

> However, this only cleans up cron entries with the status »success« or »missed« and does not clean old entries with the status »pending«.

Simple Script: to delete cron_schedule records created a day ago copied from optiweb.com link above.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$rootDirectory = *Magento root directory*;
require $rootDirectory . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('cron_schedule');


$sql = "DELETE FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";

try{
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
}catch(Exception $ex){
    print_r($ex);
}
```

Seems to do the trick, although I'm not sure about the interval may bump it to 7 days.

Comment: also useful when you want to clear it one time, here's the full SQL statement: ```DELETE FROM `cron_schedule` WHERE `created_at` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)```

Comment: Also in a long running Magento 2 site, I found that running optimize table on everything seemed to reduce disk usage by a lot. (A site with mirsvit elastic search module with large full text index files on disk in /var/mysql/magento dir.)