# bin/magento cron:run running for a long time

Tags: magento2, cli

the `bin/magento cron:run` entry in my crontab seems to cause a rather high load on the cpu (php's and mysql's cpu usage are permanently both at around 25% each) - I checked by disabling the crontab entries.

When I run `bin/magento cron:run` manually, it runs for about a minute - how can I find out what is causing this behaviour?

I already tried disabling a few suspicious modules, with no luck!

Comment: I have just suddenly noticed similar behaviour on one of my sites. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: not yet, but i'm still interrested in a solution. for now i just deactivated the cron jobs

Comment: I cleared my cron_schedule table within my database and it cleared mine up? Not sure if it was the same issue that I had as i run mine for atleast 20 mins and it never finished but after that it takes a second or 2.

Comment: some processes are running since before the VM launch, which means they broke and never got to update their status, and magento cannot clean them (only STATUS_SUCCESS, STATUS_MISSED, STATUS_ERROR get cleaned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@harri was right - since `bin/magento cron:run` seems to work through all the entries in the `magento.cron_schedule` table, this is what slows down the system when there are a lot of entries.

I dont have a mail server set, so all the jobs that try to send emails are pending - an easy fix is to either set the mail server, or regularly clear the `cron_schedule` table!

Comment: mail server like SMTP ?